# java.io.FileNotFoundException when getInputStream

Tags: android

i try to get a json string from my webservice and i use this method.

```
public static String getData(String serverURL) {
    String Content = "no";
    /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    // Send data
    try {
        // Defined URL where to send data
        URL url = new URL(serverURL);
        // Send POST data request
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(false);
        // Get the server response
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        // Read Server Response
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Append server response in string
            sb.append(line + "");
        }

        // Append Server Response To Content String
        Content = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    return Content;
}
```

it's ok when i use

```
serverURL = " http://10.1.40.149:9000/api/shop/deleteshop?data={"shopId":3}";
```

but when i use

```
serverURL = "http://10.1.40.149:9000/api/shop/updateshop?data={"fax":"data","tel":"data","contactTitle":"data","addr":"data","url":"data,"shopType":"data","issuedAt":"data","email":"data","shopId":data,"contactName":"data","description":"data","shopName":"data","province":"data","telNumber":"data"}";
```

it throw exception

```
03-20 22:22:03.850: I/System.out(1117): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.1.40.149:9000/api/shop/updateshop?data={"fax":"data","tel":"data","contactTitle":"data","addr":"data","url":"data,"shopType":"data","issuedAt":"data","email":"data","shopId":data,"contactName":"data","description":"data","shopName":"data","province":"data","telNumber":"data"}
```

any body can tell me why ?

p/s all the link i check in web browser it's ok

Comment: check your url . Are you trying to pass data = json string? . if so check if its correct json format. I think the "url" = "data" is not closed.

Comment: i dont want show my data so i replace it by "data"!